# How to generate sample 401, 403 http responses?

Tags: httprequest, fiddler, httpresponse, http-status-code-403, http-status-code-401

I want to generate sample http 401 403 responses in fiddler, how do I do that? is there any sites I can point to get this?

Comment: you might try asking this question at Server Fault

Answer (score 2):

Under Inspectors tab, there is one called **Auth** in regards to the 401.

[Read here for more details](http://blogs.msdn.com/ieinternals/archive/2009/11/22/Clipboard-Paste-Bug-in-Windows-7-Password-Prompt.aspx)

Comment: oh, no need to thank me!  just push that little up-arrow next to my answer :)